# Symfony parse error in output.php when creating project in laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Installed laravel 5.6
Have PHP 7.0 installed as well. 
When I try

```
laravel new sample-project
```

it creates the required files and dependencies but bails with an error  below:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/johndoe/laravel/sample-project/vendor/symfony/console/Output/Output.php on line 40
```

Have a feeling this might be due to issues with the symfony file but not sure how to go about getting the right version or making a change in Output.php

Trying any other command such as

```
php artisan list
```

results in the same error

Composer relevant section denoting laravel 5.6 / php 7.1.3

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Based on the answer I had to create a project with laravel version 5.5 which means I had to use

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel sample-project "5.5.*"
```

That worked.

Comment: php 7 is not enough . These are the server requirements https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) requires PHP > 7.1.3

> you will need to make sure your server meets the following
>   requirements:
>
> ```
> PHP >= 7.1.3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to edit the $PATH in my .bashrc file, because it was picking up an old version of php.

```
> whereis php
> echo $PATH
```

I found the correct version of php here:  /opt/php71/bin

So now my .bashrc file looks like this:

```
export PATH=/opt/php71/bin:$PATH
```

This fixed the error I was getting in composer, AND now php artisan also works!

:-D

PS.  The version of php that you're using in the shell may be different from the version used to serve your site.  That can be fixed in cpanel's php selector.